# How to mount /data from different storage in Android x86?

Tags: android

I built a generic_x86.iso and installed in vmware. However, I cannot choose device to mount /data during installation. I want to mount none device which is DRAM to /data with a memory filesystem, and I will use androbench to test it, so I want to mount /data seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Mounting of the data partition is typically handled from a file such as init.rc found in the root directory of the boot image (ie, the image packed onto the kernel as a gziped cpio archive)